# KeyError: "The name 'predictions/accuracy/Mean:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist...."

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am using tensorflow1.4cpu version on my ubuntu16.04.
I have previously trained a convnet model on mnist dataset.

Now i want to access the model again and predict accuracy on mnist.test.images. I successfully load the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
images = mnist.test.images[0:1000]
labels = mnist.test.labels[0:1000]
sess=tf.Session()

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('tradConv_mnistModel/tradConvMnist-
10000.meta')

saver.restore(sess,
tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./tradConv_mnistModel'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

In the previously trained graph i printed the name of accuracy which is:

```
with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(
                       tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print(accuracy.name)
     "predictions/accuracy/Mean:0"
```

But when i try to evaluate accuracy with the newly loaded graph i get the following error:

```
tensor_name = "predictions/accuracy/Mean:0"
accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
       x: images, y_: labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

KeyError: "The name 'predictions/accuracy/Mean:0' refers to a Tensor 
which does not exist. The operation, 'predictions/accuracy/Mean', does 
not exist in the graph."
```

also i printed all the tensors_name in the saved graph and indeed that tensor_name does not exit.

So my question is how can i evaluate the accuracy of a trained model a test data after reloading?

Comment: Guessing: is the saver/meta-graph saved before the accuracy ops are added? Can you check that the op exists in the graph with that name when the MetaGraph is created?

Comment: Hi I already fixed the issue.    The accuracy is defined before the saver and is saved in the graph, but it is not present in the metafile. I do not know the difference between graph and methgraph. I also do not know how to checked whether the name was created in the metagraph.                After several attempts i figured this method tf.train.import_meta_graph('tradConv_mnistModel/tradConvMnist-
10000.meta')     does not work at all. But     tf.train.Saver().restore     works! And using that i fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The method    tf.train.Saver().restore    works. But the other method 
   tf.train.import_meta_graph('tradConv_mnistModel/tradConvMnis‌​t- 10000.meta')    does not work!

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you end up deleting the statement "saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('tradConv_mnistModel/tradConvMnist-
10000.meta')" altogether and replaced it with "tf.train.Saver().restore"? Where did you specify the file path? did you include the .meta extension in the file name? Tx